# Error during MikTex Installation UTF-8 convertion to wide character string error

Tags: errors, miktex

I am trying to install MikTex in a Windows 10 laptop and when the installation is almost finished I get this error and I don´t know how to solve it.

loading lightweight database...
108 [0x0000063c] INFO initexmf null - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
 108 [0x0000063c] INFO initexmf null - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
 113 [0x0000063c] INFO initexmf null - Registering root
Error: Conversion from UTF-8 byte sequence to wide character string did not succeed.

Thanks for your help beforehand.

Comment: Report it in the miktex github issue tracker.

Comment: Yes, as @UlrikeFischer noted, that is  MikTeX issue, not a TeX language issue. On this site, we are not involved with the details of installers. But if you must have MikTeX immediately, you might try the portable version; sometimes it works when the program-install version fails.

Comment: Not a lot we can do, I'm afraid. If you can give more details and reproduce the issue you can log an issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex. But please keep in mind there are very many variables to reproducing the issue. Just a guess: Does your user name or the folder you want to install MikTeX to contain non-ASCII chars?

Comment: Yes, the folder name contains one of those characters, may that be the issue then?

Comment: The error was the one moewe said, there was a character with an accent in the name of the folder, I changed the path and everything went correct. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.